# Using tkinter checkboxes to select dataframes for folium

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, folium, choropleth

I'm a beginner with tkinter and i'm trying to implement tkinter into creating folium choropleth maps with pandas dataframes.
It'd look something like this.

[image: It'd look something like this.]

Here's the code for this:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def var_states():
   print("data1: %d,\ndata2: %d,\ndata3: %d,\ndata4: %d,\ndata5: %d,\ndata6: %d," % (var1.get(), var2.get(),var3.get(), var4.get(),var5.get(), var6.get()))

Label(master, text="What data would you like to see?:").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Data1", variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Data2", variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Data3", variable=var3).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
var4 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Data4", variable=var4).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
var5 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Data5", variable=var5).grid(row=5, sticky=W)
var6 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Data6", variable=var6).grid(row=6, sticky=W)


Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=7, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Generate', command=var_states).grid(row=8, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

Now it prints either 0 or 1 (1 if the data is selected), but I would like it to select a dataframe so I could use it as data(d5) in my choropleth code:

```
def choromapping(name, col1):
        choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
            geo_data=kunnat_geo,
            name=name,
            data=d5,
            columns=['Kunta',col1],
            key_on='feature.properties.Name',
            fill_color='OrRd',
            fill_opacity=0.8,
            line_opacity=0.2,
            legend_name=name,
            show=False
        ).add_to(map)
```

[Example dataframe.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10FULaQ7f4lfWdPpk4bzwlD9yymGrL14d/view?usp=sharing)
[My geojson.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GZljNjbIXsx55xopN9_DDlOb0Pi9Eclz/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should avoid wild imports as that may create conflicts with other wild import methods.
2. `Checkbutton` does not have to use an `IntVar` as its variable. In your case a `StringVar` will actually serve better.
3. Create your dataframes in `var_states` and create a dictionary to hold the dataframes.
4. Use the `keys` of the dictionary as the `onvalue` of your `Checkbuttons`. When selected, this passess the dictionary key as the value to your `var_states` function.
5. Use the passed value(s) to `var_states` as the key to call the corresponding `dictionary` `dataframe`, filtering out the `offvalue` state.
6. Pass the called `dataframe(s)` to the `choromapping` function.

The code below sums up the description above:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

master = tk.Tk()

def choromapping(name, col1, data):
    print(data)


def var_states():
    #create data frames
    data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name1', 'Age1'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name2', 'Age2'])
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name3', 'Age3'])
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name4', 'Age4'])
    df5 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name5', 'Age5'])
    df6 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name6', 'Age6'])

    df_dict = {
    'df1': df1,
    'df2': df2,
    'df3': df3,
    'df4': df4,
    'df5': df5,
    'df6': df6
    }

    variables = (var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get(), var5.get(), var6.get())
    for var in variables:
        if var != 'None':
            choromapping(None, None, df_dict[var])

    #print("data1:", variables)

tk.Label(master, text="What data would you like to see?:").grid(row=0, sticky='W')

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var1.set(None)
tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Data1", variable=var1, onvalue='df1', offvalue=None).grid(row=1, sticky='W')

var2 = tk.StringVar()
var2.set(None)
tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Data2", variable=var2, onvalue='df2', offvalue=None).grid(row=2, sticky='W')

var3 = tk.StringVar()
var3.set(None)
tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Data3", variable=var3, onvalue='df3', offvalue=None).grid(row=3, sticky='W')

var4 = tk.StringVar()
var4.set(None)
tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Data4", variable=var4, onvalue='df4', offvalue=None).grid(row=4, sticky='W')

var5 = tk.StringVar()
var5.set(None)
tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Data5", variable=var5, onvalue='df5', offvalue=None).grid(row=5, sticky='W')

var6 = tk.StringVar()
var6.set(None)
tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Data6", variable=var6, onvalue='df6', offvalue=None).grid(row=6, sticky='W')


tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=7, sticky='W', pady=4)
tk.Button(master, text='Generate', command=var_states).grid(row=8, sticky='W', pady=4)
master.mainloop()
```